# Java login and create account with a frame and redirect after to another frame

Tags: java, file, authentication

Hi I am new to Java and I wanted to learn how to make one program that will create accounts that will be stored in a file in the file of the code and then later you can access it to enter and go to a main program to do something else, I passed all day looking for but everyone using GUI so I do not see the code and it doesn't work well so I wanted to ask to people from here thank you in advance

Comment: [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Scanner library, which will download text from the console.
Sample part of the program

```
Scanner download = new Scanner (System.in);
String login = download .nextLine ();
```

In the login variable, you store the String entered in the input;)

More information :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/